# How to get a form to default to browser style

Tags: html, forms, css, default

I have a simple Submit form button, which is getting a style from another stylesheet that can't be edited. I want this button to use the default browser styling though inorder to fit in with the rest of the site.

Is there a CSS or HTML method where I can specify "use default".

**HTML**

```
<form action="/example.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="example" value="example">
<input type="submit" value="View Basket">
</form>
```

*Note "None" doesn't work as there is no border then obviously!*

FYI. I have done some basic research and looked through SO but can't actually see anything

Comment: Which properties are getting overridden?

Comment: border, background, cursor, padding, color - So not just one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the properties with a selector having high specificity or `!important`. Inspect the element and check which are the properties getting overridden and manually set them to default.

Most of the css properties have value `initial`.

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/2A5Vh/)

Comment: I appreciated that I can override properties with important, but this doesn't address the problem of setting them to their DEFAULT values. each browser displays slightly differently and I want to allow it to do so.

Comment: @tim.baker that is what `initial` does.. didn't you notice..? it resets that particular property back to how it was initially loaded..